# I'm getting Runtime Error when submitting answer to online judge. What could be the cause?

Tags: java, graph-theory, breadth-first-search

Link to the problem : https://vjudge.net/problem/UVA-1665

[image]

This is my code so far it works on my end with the sample input provided by the problem statement, i already tried to change the class name from class problemb to public class Main as someone else did with a similar issue but no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

class problemb {
  static int dx[] = {-1, 0, 1, 0};
  static int dy[] = {0, 1, 0, -1};

  static int[][] map;
  static boolean[][] visited;

  static int n, m;
  static int t;
  static int[] years;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int z = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

    for (int i = 0; i < z; i++) {
      String[] nm = br.readLine().split(" ");
      n = Integer.parseInt(nm[0]);
      m = Integer.parseInt(nm[1]);

      map = new int[n][m];
      visited = new boolean[n][m];

      for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        String[] row = br.readLine().split(" ");
        for (int k = 0; k < m; k++) {
          map[j][k] = Integer.parseInt(row[k]);
        }
      }

      t = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
      years = new int[t];

      String[] tValues = br.readLine().split(" ");
      for (int j = 0; j < t; j++) {
        years[j] = Integer.parseInt(tValues[j]);
      }
      br.close();
      
      int[] results = new int[t];
      
      for (int j = 0; j < t; j++) {
        int year = years[j];
        int areas = 0;
      
        // Reset the visited array for the current year
        visited = new boolean[n][m];
      
        for (int y = 0; y < n; y++) {
          for (int x = 0; x < m; x++) {
            if (!visited[y][x] && map[y][x] > year) {
              areas++;
              bfs(y, x, year);
            }
          }
        }
      
        results[j] = areas;
      }
      
      for (int j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
        System.out.print(results[j]);
        if (j < results.length - 1) {
          System.out.print(" ");
        }
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
  static void bfs(int y, int x, int year) {
    int[][] queue = new int[n * m][2];
    int head = 0, tail = 0;
    queue[tail][0] = y;
    queue[tail][1] = x;
    tail++;
    visited[y][x] = true;
  
    while (head < tail) {
      int yy = queue[head][0];
      int xx = queue[head][1];
      head++;
  
      for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        int ny = yy + dy[i];
        int nx = xx + dx[i];
  
        if (ny < 0 || ny >= n || nx < 0 || nx >= m || visited[ny][nx] || map[ny][nx] <= year) {
          continue;
        }
  
        visited[ny][nx] = true;
        queue[tail][0] = ny;
        queue[tail][1] = nx;
        tail++;
      }
    }
  }
}
```